# Analytic solution to optimization involving step function

Tags: optimization

Say I've observed some samples of two random IID variables, $\{x_i\}$ and $\{y_i\}$.  Is there an analytic solution to the following optimization problem?

$$
\underset{a}{\mathrm{argmax}} \sum_i \left[ y_i \mathrm{Sign}(x_i) - c \right] \mathbb{I}_{\{|x_i| > a\}}
$$

If not, what numerical approach is recommended?

Comment: are the variables independent from each other?

Comment: @Aksakal No, $x_i$ is IID with $x_{i+1}$, but is correlated with $y_i$ (but not $y_{i+1}$).

Comment: It's unclear what you are optimizing, because according to everything in this question for any possible $a$ the expression is a *random variable,* not a number.  Did you perhaps forget to take an expectation somewhere?  If not, then we ought to conclude the question has nothing to do with random variables and only with the *data* $(x_i,y_i),$ and so assumptions of independence or correlation would be irrelevant.  Is that what you really intend?

Comment: @whuber Yes, probably shouldn't have mentioned that they're IID to avoid confusion.  The optimization is only using a specific set of realizations of the random variables (i.e., the observed data).

Comment: Have you made efforts to simplify your question?  For instance, why not replace all $y_i$ by $y_i\operatorname{Sign}x_i$?  Similarly, you can reduce the problem to non-negative $x_i.$  That shows you're trying to maximize the sum of absolute deviations between the (new) $y_i$ and the constant $c$ within the upper tail of the $x_i.$  Obviously there's no "analytic" solution, because the problem requires you to specify all the data--there's no possibility of any simplifying formula.  You can find the solution  by sorting the $x_i$ and scanning downwards.

Comment: Thanks.  The sorting by $|x_i|$ and scanning downwards idea makes sense.  By "analytic", I meant that given the data, there would be a linear algebra solution analagous to ordinary least squares.